# Running ECS service on 2 container instances (ECS instances)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS service which has a requirement that it should be running on exactly 2 container instances.  How can this be achieved? I could not find any specific place in container definition, where I can fix the number of ECS instances.

Comment: A since ECS service can run only on one instance. So its not clear what do you want to do with two instances? Run two copies of same ecs service?

Comment: @Marcin.. One thing is unclear to me. Is it that each ECS task runs on one container instance alone?
I mean, if we have say 5 tasks for a service, these 5 tasks run on 5 different container instances?

Comment: I see what you mean. You want to have a service running two copies of same task? Yes, then you can run them on different instances.

Comment: Right. Multiple copies of tasks for a single service can be run. I have a similar scenario. My question is, will each task copy run on one container ?

Comment: As I remember, Fargate launch type supports many tasks but Fargate has some limitations. I think you can consider it.

Comment: Yes, if you use `DAEMON` placement strategy, then each copy of a task will be on different instance.

Comment: @FranxiHidro, We are currently running the whole infra on EC2 and may be in future, we might plan to migrate to Fargate. But, as of now, we are planning to use EC2

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this. One is to deploy your ECS service on Fargate. When you do so and you set your task count to, say, 2 ... ECS will deploy your 2 tasks onto 2 separate and dedicated operating systems/VMs managed by AWS. Two or more tasks can never be colocated to one of these VMs. It's always a 1 task : 1 VM relationship.

If you are using EC2 as your launch type and you want to make sure your service deploys exactly 1 task per instance the easiest way would be to configure your ECS service as type `DAEMON`. In this case you don't even need (or can't) configure the number of tasks in your service because ECS will always deploy 1 task per EC2 instance that is part of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of creating service you will find the field Number of tasks it means that how many container you want exactly. If you write 1 than it will launch only 1 and if you write 2 then it will launch 2 . I Hope you understand